# Code running for longer period to evaluate

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximize

0I have the following code where I want to maximize a stochastic function based on two variables. The code is taking a very long time to evaluate but still not giving answers. Can anyone help?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
C1 = 100;
C2 = 150;
P = 500;
M = 10000;
n1 = 140*(1 - Exp[-0.1*a1]);
n2 = 40*(1 - Exp[-0.1*a2]);
B1 = 2500;
B2 = 4500;
pdf1[a1_, x1_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[n1*a1, Sqrt[n1]*2], x1];
pdf2[a2_, x2_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[n2*a2, Sqrt[n2]*2], x2];
jdf[a1_, x1_, a2_, x2_] = 
 PDF[BinormalDistribution[{n1*a1, n2*a2}, {Sqrt[n1]*2, Sqrt[n2]*2}, 
   0], {x1, x2}];
jexpt[a1_, a2_] = B1*n1 + B2*n2 + Integrate[((-C1)*x1)*pdf1[a1, x1], {x1, 0, n1*a1}] + Integrate[((-C1)*x2)*pdf1[a2, x2], {x2, 0, n2*a2}] + 
   Integrate[(P*(x1 - n1*a1) - C1*(x1 + x2))*jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2], {x2, 0, n2*a2}, {x1, n1*a1, M}] + Integrate[(P*(x1 - n1*a1) - C1*M - C2*x1)*jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2], 
    {x2, 0, n2*a2}, {x1, M, Infinity}] + Integrate[(P*(x2 - n2*a2) - C1*(x1 + x2))*jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2], {x2, 0, n1*a1}, {x1, n2*a2, M}] + 
   Integrate[(P*(x2 - n2*a2) - C1*M - C2*x2)*jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2], {x2, 0, n1*a1}, {x1, M, Infinity}] + 
   Integrate[(P*((x2 - n2*a2) + (x1 - n1*a1)) - C2*(x1 + x2))*jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2], {x2, M, Infinity}, {x1, M, Infinity}]

Maximize[{jexpt[a1, a2], a1 >= 0 && a2 >= 0}, {a1, a2}]
```

Can anyone check where it is wrong as I aborted the evaluation?

NMaximize solves the code but it does not give me answers.

Comment: My guess: Decimal points (`-0.1`) indicate (approximate) floating-point numbers, and an exact solver like `Maximize` works best on exact input (e.g. `-1/10`). Either use a numerical solver (`NMaximize`) or try the problem with exact coefficients.  At first glance, getting an exact solution would be extremely lucky, imo.  Second possibility, if the `Integrate` calls do not yield answers, then they will be recomputed every time `jexpt[a1, a2]` is evaluated. That would use a lot of time. -- "`NMaximize `solves but does not give answers." Unsure what that means. To me "solves" = "gives answers."

Comment: What answers are you getting? It should give the values of a1 and a2, right?

Comment: Is there ANY chance there might be a textbook closed form solution to any of those integrals? That might speed this up a lot. Each of those integrals is taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

C1 = 100;
C2 = 150;
P = 500;
M = 10000;
n1 = 140*(1 - Exp[-a1/10]);
n2 = 40*(1 - Exp[-a2/10]);
B1 = 2500;
B2 = 4500;

pdf1[a1_, x1_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[n1*a1, Sqrt[n1]*2], x1];

pdf2[a2_, x2_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[n2*a2, Sqrt[n2]*2], x2];

jdf[a1_, x1_, a2_, x2_] = 
  PDF[BinormalDistribution[{n1*a1, n2*a2}, {Sqrt[n1]*2, Sqrt[n2]*2}, 0], {x1, 
    x2}];
```

The distributions require

```
assume = Simplify[
  And @@ (DistributionParameterAssumptions /@ {NormalDistribution[n1*a1, 
       Sqrt[n1]*2], NormalDistribution[n2*a2, Sqrt[n2]*2], 
      BinormalDistribution[{n1*a1, n2*a2}, {Sqrt[n1]*2, Sqrt[n2]*2}, 0]}),
  Element[{a1, a2}, Reals]]

(* Sqrt[1 - E^(-a1/10)] > 0 && Sqrt[1 - E^(-a2/10)] > 0 *)
```

Consequently, assume throughout that `{a1 > 0, a2 > 0}`

```
t[1] = AbsoluteTiming[int[1] = Assuming[a1 > 0,
      Integrate[((-C1)*x1)*pdf1[a1, x1],
       {x1, 0, n1*a1}]];][[1]]

(* 5.48624 *)

t[2] = AbsoluteTiming[int[2] = Assuming[a2 > 0,
      Integrate[((-C1)*x2)*pdf1[a2, x2],
       {x2, 0, n2*a2}]];][[1]]

(* 7.32123 *)

t[3] = AbsoluteTiming[int[3] = Assuming[a1 > 0 && a2 > 0,
      Integrate[(P*(x1 - n1*a1) - C1*(x1 + x2))*
        jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2],
       {x2, 0, n2*a2}, {x1, n1*a1, M}]];][[1]]

(* 64.0385 *)

t[4] = AbsoluteTiming[int[4] = Assuming[a1 > 0 && a2 > 0,
      Integrate[(P*(x1 - n1*a1) - C1*M - C2*x1)*
        jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2],
       {x2, 0, n2*a2}, {x1, M, Infinity}]];][[1]]

(* 48.2026 *)

t[5] = AbsoluteTiming[int[5] = Assuming[a1 > 0 && a2 > 0,
      Integrate[(P*(x2 - n2*a2) - C1*(x1 + x2))*
        jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2],
       {x2, 0, n1*a1}, {x1, n2*a2, M}]];][[1]]

(* 165.255 *)

t[6] = AbsoluteTiming[int[6] = Assuming[a1 > 0 && a2 > 0,
      Integrate[(P*(x2 - n2*a2) - C1*M - C2*x2)*
        jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2],
       {x2, 0, n1*a1}, {x1, M, Infinity}]];][[1]]

(* 59.3415 *)

t[7] = AbsoluteTiming[int[7] = Assuming[a1 > 0 && a2 > 0,
      Integrate[(P*((x2 - n2*a2) + (x1 - n1*a1)) - C2*(x1 + x2))*
        jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2], 
       {x2, M, Infinity}, {x1, M, Infinity}]];][[1]]

(* 264.437 *)
```

The total integration time is

```
Total[t /@ Range[7]]

(* 614.082 *)

jexpt[a1_, a2_] =
  B1*n1 + B2*n2 + Total[int /@ Range[7]];

LeafCount@jexpt[a1, a2]

(* 27763 *)
```

The expression for `jexpt` is very complicated. Simplifying this expression would probably be useful; however, extremely time-consuming.

```
AbsoluteTiming[{max, arg} = NMaximize[
    {jexpt[a1, a2], a1 > 0 && a2 > 0}, {a1, a2},
    WorkingPrecision -> 20] // N]

(* {1.54658, {301841., {a1 -> 11.2833, a2 -> 29.2196}}} *)
```

[`NMaximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) is fairly quick; however, there is no guarantee that this is a global maximum.

```
Off[General::munfl]

General::munfl

(* $Off["`1` is too small to represent as a normalized machine 
number; precision may be lost."] *)

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
 Show[
  Plot3D[
   Evaluate@jexpt[a1, a2], {a1, 5, 15}, {a2, 25, 35},
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.8],
   WorkingPrecision -> 30,
   MaxRecursion -> 5],
  Graphics3D[
   {Red, AbsolutePointSize[8],
    Point[{a1, a2, max} /. arg]}],
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {a1, a2, jexpt})]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. All these times are in seconds?

Comment: As stated in the documentation, "AbsoluteTiming[expr] evaluates expr, returning a list of the absolute number of seconds in real time that have elapsed, together with the result obtained."

Comment: I have tried your code with a few modifications but the NMaximize is not giving me results. Can you check?

Comment: What kind of changes did you make? Perhaps you should post a new question with the code with which you are having a problem.

Comment: Okay, will do that. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have added your code with a bit of modification. Can you check the question now?